# If matrix $A$ commutes with $B+C$, under what condition does it also commute with $B$ and $C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices

Let $A,B,C$ be real square matrices, and suppose that $A$ commutes with $B+C$, i.e., $A(B+C) = (B+C)A$. In general, this does not imply that $A$ commutes with $B$ (and therefore with $C$) as well.

My question is, under what conditions on $B$ and $C$, does $AB = BA$?

For what it's worth, I am particularly interested in the case where $A$ and $B+C$ are both symmetric, while $B$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: There is some reason to believe there is not a good answer. Let $S = B+C$; then in the case you're interested in, $C = S + (-B)$ is the unique decomposition of $C$ into its symmetric and skew-symmetric components. Your question is: given that $A$ commutes with the symmetric component, when does it commute with the skew-symmetric component? But the symmetric component does not affect the skew-symmetric component in any way. So all your conditions might just be conditions on "when does $A$ commute with a skew-symmetric matrix?" up to a substitution or two.

Answer (score 1):

I will stick to the case where $A$ is symmetric. I'm not sure that there is a satisfactory answer to your question, but here is a couple of things we can say:

1. Assume that $A$ and $C$ are symmetric and  that $B$ is skew symmetric, then $A$ commutes with $B$ and $C$.

Indeed, since $AB+AC=BA+CA (*)$, taking tranpose yields $-BA+CA=-AB+AC$, that is $-AB+AC=-BA+CA(**)$. Now sum $(*)$ and $(**)$ and divide by $2$  to get  $AC=CA$ (and thus $AB=BA$).

2. Assume $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is skew symmetric, and assume that all eigenvalues values of $A$ are pairwise distinct. Then $A$ never  commutes with $B$, unless $B=0$.

Indeed, in this case ,matrices commuting with $A$ all have the form $P(A), P\in\mathbb{R}[X]$. Hence if $B$ is skew symmetric and commutes with $A$, then $B=P(A)$, and thus $-B=B^t=P(A^t)=P(A)=B$, hence $B=0$.